# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'distinct'

Tags: python, dictionary, bson

I have a bson file, and i dont know what have inside of the file. So, a read the file. And now, i still trying to found the value of each key, but not is easy.  Because, i receive the messange:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'distinct'

What i do?

[image]

Am I writing more code? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do understand your question, `read_content['_id']` should suffice.

So the code should be:

```py
read_content = bson.json_util.loads(content)
print(read_content['_id'])
```